# How to speed up a python for loop going over outlook emails

Tags: python, performance, outlook

I wrote a script in python 3.5 which goes over all the emails in my outlook "Inbox" folder, does something, then moves the emails from the inbox folder to the "Sent Items" folder. Due to some problems with pyinstaller i had to downgrade to python 2.7 and after that the code became really slow in going over each email.

**I would like to know if there's a way to speed my code up easily, I believe the main problem is the only for loop i have in my code, which is the following:**

```
import os
import win32com.client
import itertools
import shutil

OlSaveAsType = {
    "olTXT": 0,
    "olRTF": 1,
    "olTemplate": 2,
    "olMSG": 3,
    "olDoc": 4,
    "olHTML": 5,
    "olVCard": 6,
    "olVCal": 7,
    "olICal": 8
}

desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
newpath = desktop + '\\Mails2'
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = outlook.Folders("My Main Folder")
inbox = folder.Folders("Inbox")
sent_items = folder.Folders("Sent Items")

messages = inbox.Items
a = (len(messages))
message = messages.GetFirst()


#for message in messages:
for _ in itertools.repeat(None, a):

    messages = inbox.Items
    message = messages.GetFirst()

    Subject = message.subject
    Sender = message.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
    Time = message.ReceivedTime
    message.SaveAs(newpath + '\\' + Sender + ".msg", OlSaveAsType['olMSG'])

    message.Move(sent_items)
    message = messages.GetNext()
```

the commented line (for message in messages:) seems to be faster than itertools, however when i tried using it, for some reason i could never get all the messages in a subfolder, first it would take only half the messages (turned out i was decreasing the message container with each loop by moving the mail to a different folder) so i tried removing messages.GetNext() as well to make the for loop do all the work, but still there would be a message left unmoved, only itertools with the length of inmail items seemed to do the job.

Comment: Where is the most time spent? What did you measure? Is it CPU-bound or IO-bound?

Comment: The for loop takes the most time, messages are moved 1 every 4 seconds or so.: for _ in itertools.repeat(None, a):

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, since you are modifying the collection, you should not use gGtFirst/GetNext. Use a dowb loop from Items.Count down to 1.

Secondly, looping over *all* items in a folder is expected to be slow.